# Camel type conversion fails in Fuse

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have a camel route with a cxf producer (Camel v2.10):

```
<to uri="cxf:bean:myCxfEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
```

I know that camel does a conversion to *CxfPayload*, so I added the following imports to OSGi header:

```
org.apache.camel.component.cxf,
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter,
org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb
```

So when the producer is triggered the following exception occurs:

```
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: my.package.Foo to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload
```

I can get rid of this exception by restarting the camel-jaxb bundle, but getting rid of it is not enough: I need to prevent it, because it happens every time I restart Fuse.

Any idea is highly appreciated :)

**EDIT**

It turned out that the issue doesn't always come up. Sometimes it works after restart, sometimes it doesn't. I tried to play with bundle-levels but it remained unpredictable. I have a feeling that it might be Camel who doesn't load the converters correctly, but based on the trace log it looks like the CxfPayloadConverter is always loaded into the ConverterRegistry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 10 hours of tracing and debugging I figured out the solution: I added a manual marshalling before the CXF Producer, like this:

```
    <marshal ref="myDataFormat"/>
    <to uri="cxf:bean:myCxfEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
```

Why: My assumption was that it's OK to send any POJO to the Camel CXF Endpoint and it'll be able to handle the Conversion. The only thing I can think of is it matters that in what order Camel loads the Converters. Every second time when it worked in fuse it could make a *POJO -> String -> CxfPayload* conversion so it could transitively resolve the conversion. I decided  not to rely on this transitive conversion logic and checked all the loaded converters. I found that there are certain direct converters registered in the registry between XML *Node/Element -> CxfPayload* classes. So I decided to trick Camel's logic with marshalling my POJO.

Comment: camel-jaxb bundle has a fallback converter which can turn the POJO into XML. I guest you may need to do something (add require bundle or define the dataformat yourself) to make sure camel-jaxb bundle is started before your application bundle.

Comment: It was a runtime exception so all bundles were up and the Converters were loaded when I first triggered the service. I think that there's no real need to import the converter packages in the header: Camel by default shares the Converter registry with the bundles and the maintenance of the registry is handled by the camel-core bundle. Also I saw the FallbackConverter was loaded, so it is more like some Camel bug with the conversion chain/registry init.